# Redirect for anonymus user doesn´t work from Controller

Tags: 8, redirection

Community,
i´ve got a simple COntroller for redirect my users by visiting a special path (localhost/drupal8/check). At the moment the redirect works for the administrator and for registrated user, if they are logged in, but not for the quests of my site (i know that it is only a local site).

```
namespace Drupal\testmodule\Controller; 
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class EntityChecker extends ControllerBase {

  public function redirectToFront($bundle, $label) { return $this->redirect('<front>');

}
}
```

In the log i´m getting the following error:

> [30-Jul-2018 09:30:25 UTC] RuntimeException: Failed to start the
>   session because headers have already been sent by
>   "C:\wamp64\www\drupal8\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Response.php" at
>   line 1274. in
>   C:\wamp64\www\drupal8\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage.php
>   on line 141 #0
>   C:\wamp64\www\drupal8\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManager.php(164):
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start()

Thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: What does your route look like?

Comment: localhost/drupal8 is the base URL and the route is  localhost/drupal8/testvalue1/testvalue2  getting these parameters working fine, but not the dedirect to the front

Comment: what does your `*.routing.yml` look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\testmodule\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class EntityChecker extends ControllerBase {

  public function redirectToFront($bundle, $label) {
    $response = new RedirectResponse("/");
    $response->send();
  }

}
```